# How can I get urlopen to work with a list of urls from a file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of urls from a file to work with urlopen so I can iterate through them and work with each url.

I was able to do what I wanted perfectly with one url directly passed as an argument, but I want to be able to do the same with a list retrieved from a file. It can go into the hundreds so ideally I'd like to iterate through them from an Excel or CSV file.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import re
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('links.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        string_row = (str(row))
        after_strip = string_row.strip('\'')
        page_source = urlopen(after_strip)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source.read(), 'html.parser')

        tag_with_word = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("//www.someword"))
        print(tag_with_word)
```

When I try to print the rows, it comes out perfectly fine, but if I try to use it in urlopen(row) it gives an error. So I tried converting it to string and then stripping the apostrophe. Sadly it still didn't work.

I'm pretty new to Python, having just installed it last week. Can anyone help?

Comment: *it gives an error*. Please add the traceback of the error

Comment: How many columns are there in links.csv?

Comment: What error do you get? Also, can you print out `string_row` to see what the URL looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping.

I figured it out myself a few hours after posting this, and completely forgot about here. My apologies.

For the benefit of anyone, here is my final working code:

```
import re
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('links.csv','r') as csvfile:
  for row in csvfile.readlines():
    #print (row)

    try:
        page_source = urllib2.urlopen(row)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        print ("Exception - "+row)
        continue
    #print (page_source.read())

    if "xxx" in row:
        print("XXX - "+row)

    else:

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source.read(), 'html.parser')

        #print(soup.prettify())
        tag_with_xxx = soup.find_all(href=re.compile(".xxx."))

        if not tag_with_xxx:
            print("No tag - "+row)

        #else:
            #print("With tag - "+row)
```

To sum it up, I open the CSV file with the links, iterate through it. First I needed to check the URL itself if it contained a certain string, and if not, go deeper and check the page-source's contents for the presence of the same.

At some points the URL failed to open breaking the script, so I added a `try` block to catch it, and `continue` to make sure the loop goes on after.

I've masked some confidential bits.

Thanks again, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by a wrong format (encoding) of your URL.

To correct your problem you should convert your URL to utf-8 before parsing it with openurl like so.

```
string_row = str(row)
after_encode = string_row.encode('utf-8')
page_source = urlopen(after_encode)
```

You could simply make the string_row to an encoded URL right away, like:

```
encoded_url = str(row).encode('utf-8')
page_source = urlopen(encoded_url)
```

If this doesn't work, could you please post your error to make things more clear to answer?